# Meteor - event on {{if currentUser}} content loaded

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

I have a template

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
{{/if}}
```

I want do add

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

But in methods of template:

- onCreated
- onRendered

content of `{{#if currentUser}}` is not accessible because collection with user is loaded after template. I can use `setTimeout`, but this is non stable solution. I can to type in template

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
    <script>
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    </script>
{{/if}}
```

but this is not elegant.

How to catch rendering of content in block `{{if currentUser}}` in correct way? Or maybe should I not use this syntax generally and there is other manner of checking is user is loaded. If yes, link to proper tutorial please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to make the content of the `if` another template, and then use the `onRendered` or `onCreated` methods of that template.

```html
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{> datePicker}}
{{/if}}
...

<template name="datePicker">
  <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
</template>
```

JS:

```js
Template.datePicker.onCreated(() => {
  // something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Christian Fritz's answer works well.

In case you don't want to create a new template because of some other issues, you can also try this in the `onRendered` callback:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if ($('#datetimepicker')[0]) {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  }
});
```